# Can't move focus from table view to adjoining button on tvOS

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, tvos

I have a single ViewController which contains a Table View on the left and a few labels on the right. Navigating through the table view entries works fine (up/down). Focus is no problem there. Even the related text in the labels is updated just fine using `tableView:didUpdateFocusInContext`.

The interface looks like this:
[image]

However, the button on the right ("Jetzt ansehen") never gets focus. When I use the debugger (as suggested in the official documentation), it doesn't include the button in the focusable area at all:

[image]

I really tried to solve this using `UIFocusGuide`, but I have no real idea how to accomplish that, yet.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial you can use to solve your problem with focus guides: http://blog.prolificinteractive.com/2015/10/23/using-the-focus-guide-to-improve-your-tvos-apps/

Comment: Still wasn't able to figure this out, but solved it by using a SplitViewController. Thanks for the tutorials, tough. Helped me to better understand the concept behind focus guides.